# The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads

Tags: wordpress, macos, unix, chmod

I am trying to upload pictures in WordPress but I get this error:

> The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads.

I am running it in localhost but the answers I have found are to change the folder permissions to 777 on the server.

I tried making an uploads folder myself, but it's of no use and there is no option to change the folder permissions to anything except read and write.

I'm using XAMPP on Mac OS X; I'm new to WordPress - how can I fix this?

Comment: Change permissions as mentioned by @Danny Beckett

Comment: Also.. check the size of the file size you are uploading.. the server might be rejecting it due to a large size..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that your wordpress directory is "owned" by the correct user, you should see your problem resolved if you set the permissions to 755.

Log on to your server, and `cd` to `wp-content`, then run:

```
chmod 755 uploads
```

Answer (score 20):

It is *most likely* a permissions issue. Find the user processes running on the site by navigating to your sites `wp-content` folder on the server your site is on. Then type this;

```
ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
```

Ignore root, but look at the other users

```
root      2507  0.0  0.3 423820 14328 ?        Ss   Aug04   0:51 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    4653  0.5  1.9 483900 77252 ?        S    16:27   0:14 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    4654  0.5  2.1 500160 84912 ?        S    16:27   0:13 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    4656  0.8  2.0 484708 78712 ?        S    16:27   0:21 /usr/sbin/httpd
...
```

For me it actually *was* apache (usually www-data). Finally change the users of the `uploads` folder to this user;

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache uploads
```

*(make sure you are in the directory above the uploads folder when running this command)*

This will permit the **correct** user to access this directory using the **correct** access permissions of 755.

By using the dreadful '777' advice of others, you are simply allowing the correct user to access the directory assigned to the ***incorrect*** user - as well as anyone else who can access that directory!

Comment: After entering `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` within `wp-content`, I tried to cd into "uploads" and typed the suggested command in the terminal: 

`chown -R myusername:myusername uploads`

This gave me an error - No such file or directory. Am I misunderstanding how you change the users of the `uploads` file?

Comment: Your command is trying to change files in `uploads/uploads/` which doesn't exist. You need to go up (back) one level. Use `ls` to ensure you can see the `uploads` folder listed before you run the command.

Comment: Went back one level and used `ls` to see the `uploads` folder listed. Tried `chmod 755 uploads` and `sudo chmod 755 uploads` and nothing happened. Then tried `chown -R daemon:daemon uploads` and got this: http://imgur.com/a/vbIun (the red lines are crossing out myfullname).

Comment: I don't use a mac but you should take a look at this answer - https://superuser.com/a/518545/364893 You will probably need to use `-R` on each command and change file to `uploads`

Comment: That said, you will need to then reset the permissions on the files as that answer suggests ` Give everyone read-write permission to file` which is exactly what we are trying to avoid

Comment: I got it to work - the key was to just add `sudo`  before `chown -R daemon:daemon uploads`. The `chown` command requires super user rights. So `sudo chown -R daemon: daemon uploads`.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, I updated my answer to be more explicit. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend, for security's sake, instead of

```
sudo chmod 777 uploads
```

which gives permissions (read, write, execute) to the user who owns the folder (the root), to other users in the file's Group and to other users not in the file's group (anyone else).

```
sudo chmod 755 uploads
```

which gives all permissions to the owner, but only read and execute permissions to the other users

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has landed here but using a Windows / IIS platform then you can achieve the same thing by giving modify permissions to the `Everyone` group for your `wp-content\uploads` directory.

[image: permissions dialog]

Answer (score 1):

another possible reason is wrong owner and group of `uploads` folder.

try

```
chown -R _www:_www wp-content/uploads
```

assuming your apache group and owner is `_www`

Comment: Thanks, this led me along the right path. My exact situation ended up being `chown -R web:www-data` though.