# Wordpress: Uploaded file could not be moved - how to edit owner or similar?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, ftp, file-permissions

After having created a Wordpress website on a test server, I moved it to the clients server. The website works as intended, but now I cannot upload files anymore via the Wordpress media area: I am getting a message "Uploaded file could not be moved to Uploads/.../..." (not sure about the exact English terms here, I use a different language)

Both "servers" are actually just webspaces at different providers - I have no access to the server configuration.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19020186/5641669) and its answers. Now, when I simply set file permissions of the "uploads" folder and all its contents to "777", uploading is possible again, but as is mentioned everywhere, this should not be done for security reasons.

The remaining solution would be to check if the owner of the folder and files is correct. Probably not, but: Where do I see the owner (in an FTP program like Filezilla) and how can I change it? Or what else could I do to solve this problem with the very limited possibilies I have (basically just FTP access, no control over server settings)?

FWIW: Via FTP (Filezilla) I have no problem uploading files to that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let interested users know: I contacted the providers support, they gave me the advice to update the account to a higher PHP version (by putting two lines into `.htaccess`, which I didn't know was possible), and now the problem is gone - I can upload files again, with the regular `755` setting for file permissions on the "upload folder" and its subfolders.
(BTW: PHP was 5.2(!), now 7)