# The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2019/06

Tags: php, wordpress

I bought a wordpress website using GoDaddy.

I am trying to upload a Reign theme that I purchased.

But when I try to upload the folder, it says:

"The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2019/06."

Please help.

Comment: There are alot of questions regarding the same issue on this site and many other sites if you search on google. Please try the solutions they provide and if none of them work ask a question where you explain what solutions you already tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020186/the-uploaded-file-could-not-be-moved-to-wp-content-uploads)

Answer (score 1):

As I know WordPress theme needs be uploaded to `wp-content/themes` not `wp-content/uploads`

May be you are not familiar with WordPress and using its Media library to upload theme

For your problem there are 2 ways for you:

1. Using GoDaddy panel, seek for file manager and upload theme folder to `wp-content/themes`
2. Log In to site choose `Appearance` -> `Themes` then choose `Add new` -> `Upload theme`. Here zip your theme folder and upload it

Because you bought WordPress site, normally It works well with file permission as my experience

One more thing, You can contact GoDaddy support if you lack of technical skill and not familiar with WordPress